Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection
I'm encountering an issue with Spring Boot. Recently, I upgraded the Spring Boot dependency to version 3.2.4.
When I attempt to call the following endpoint:
    @PutMapping("/{uid}/test/{state}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(
            Context context,
            @PathVariable String uid,
            @PathVariable String state
    ) throws RuntimeFunctionalException {
        this.service.updateState(uid, state, context);
    }

Output:

Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag

Is anyone else facing the same issue?

To fix the problem, add name for @RequestParam and @PathVariable annotations.
So, instead of this:
public ResponseEntity<CommandResponse> update(
    @PathVariable long param1, 
    @RequestParam String param2) {
    // ...
}

use this >>>
public ResponseEntity<CommandResponse> update(
    @PathVariable("param1") long param1, 
    @RequestParam("param2") String param2) {
    // ...
}


Please include this configuration in your POM file
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

this configuration is important <parameters>true</parameters>
For more details use this link

I got the same error as you. What I found out that is you really need to add the  '-parameters' option to Java compiler.
Depending on your build tool, you should take correct actions. Like in my case, I'm using Gradle, here is what it looks like:
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
options.compilerArgs = ['-parameters']
doFirst {
    println "Compiler args: ${options.compilerArgs}"
}}

Additionally, I use VS Code, and when I run the Application file using the Run Java (when right click), it's not working. Using the ./gradlew bootRun works as expected!
And one more thing, if you use explicit PathVariable, it should work.

I got the same error when launching tests in VS Code. Seems close problem to  to Nix_snow_cat's answer above.
There is an option in Java: Runtime  configuration / Compiler where it's possible to turn on storing parameters information (seems that with this option VS Code will compile with --parameters option).
After setting it on - tests started to execute properly in vs code.
Java: Runtime configuration -> Compiler -> [x] Store information about method parameters .
